# Is it possible to have dictionary where keys are of type bool?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

Something like this:

```
string defectGuid = null;

var dictionary = new Dictionary<bool,string> {
    {new ProjectDiscrepancyWrongLocation().Conditions(row), "88ff2dfb-6190-4ab6-b13b-68de1719eac2"},
    {new DestructionLeakiness().Conditions(row), "af018ee7-7974-45f8-a508-18359cde4108"},
    {new CoatingInsulationDefect().Conditions(row), "232b2b2e-abc0-46b2-8b8c-45fede83ad83"},
    {new CathodicProtectionUnitUnderProtectionZone().Conditions(row), "78cb3548-0d61-4809-bf28-0590dfb52010"},
    {new CoatingPaintDefect().Conditions(row), "83e82b20-efc9-4500-8ca5-bb29631ccc61"},
    {new ProjectDiscrepancyEdgesOffset().Conditions(row), "cf9c76c3-79eb-4856-8dc6-c9c7321a3ed5"},
    {new DocumentationDiscrepancyDiscrepanciesInDocumentation().Conditions(row), "d3c793bc-5840-413a-8cae-6962772b4a88"},
    {new DestructionElementDestruction().Conditions(row), "6b8924f9-5bba-4db8-b33c-099ca17a58b9"},
    {new IndicatorDefectDamage().Conditions(row), "8F2560F3-31A0-4489-9A77-387BE9347D38"}
};
foreach (var item in dictionary.Where(item => item.Key)) {
    defectGuid = item.Value;
}
return defectGuid;
```

Where one of classes is as following:

```
public class DestructionLeakiness : IDefectTypeConditions {
    public bool Conditions(string[] row) {
        return Helpers.NormalizeLocalizedString(row[4]).Contains("aaaa");
    }
}
```

The issue is there will be an error that says that key already exists.

UPDATE:

I've changed approach to the following:

```
private static string SetTypeOfDefect(string[] row)
{
    string defectGuid = null;

    var list = new List<Tuple<bool, string>>()
    {
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new ProjectDiscrepancyWrongLocation().Conditions(row), "88ff2dfb-6190-4ab6-b13b-68de1719eac2"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new DestructionLeakiness().Conditions(row), "af018ee7-7974-45f8-a508-18359cde4108"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new CoatingInsulationDefect().Conditions(row), "232b2b2e-abc0-46b2-8b8c-45fede83ad83"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new CathodicProtectionUnitUnderProtectionZone().Conditions(row), "78cb3548-0d61-4809-bf28-0590dfb52010"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new CoatingPaintDefect().Conditions(row), "83e82b20-efc9-4500-8ca5-bb29631ccc61"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new ProjectDiscrepancyEdgesOffset().Conditions(row), "cf9c76c3-79eb-4856-8dc6-c9c7321a3ed5"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new DocumentationDiscrepancyDiscrepanciesInDocumentation().Conditions(row), "d3c793bc-5840-413a-8cae-6962772b4a88"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new DestructionElementDestruction().Conditions(row), "6b8924f9-5bba-4db8-b33c-099ca17a58b9"),
        new Tuple<bool, string>(new IndicatorDefectDamage().Conditions(row), "8F2560F3-31A0-4489-9A77-387BE9347D38")
    };

    foreach (var item in list.Where(item => item.Item1))
    {
        defectGuid = item.Item2;
    }

    return defectGuid;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a dictionary of Booleans, because it is limited to only two values. This will inevitably lead to key collisions, because you plan to add more than two items to it. Good news is that you do not need a dictionary anyway, because you use it as a collection of tuples. This will work:

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<bool,string>> {
    Tuple.Create(new ProjectDiscrepancyWrongLocation().Conditions(row), "88ff2dfb-6190-4ab6-b13b-68de1719eac2")
,   Tuple.Create(new DestructionLeakiness().Conditions(row), "af018ee7-7974-45f8-a508-18359cde4108")
,   Tuple.Create(new CoatingInsulationDefect().Conditions(row), "232b2b2e-abc0-46b2-8b8c-45fede83ad83"), ...
};
return tupleList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1)?.Item2;
```

As far as a dictionary with Boolean keys is concerned, when you need a `Dictionary` key, `bool` is as good as any other type with hash code and equals.

A dictionary on a Boolean would not be a very efficient data structure, though, because you would be able to store a maximum of two strings - one for each value of `bool`. You can accomplish (nearly<sup>*</sup>) the same thing with an array of two strings, and indexing them with `cond ? 1 : 0` expression:

```
string messages[] = new string[2] { "Message on false", "Message on true"};
var msg = messages[condition ? 1 : 0];
```

<sup>*</sup> Dictionary would let you distinguish between a situation when a key is not set vs. a key is set to `null` value, while an array wouldn't let you do it.